# How can I make the navigation responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I try to make my navigation responsive but I cannot manage that. I already tried some things as you can see in my style.css. My header is already responsive but I can't manage the navigation.

This is my website on the desktop/laptop.
[image]

This is my website on mobile. I want the navigation also in the center like the picture above.
[image]

```css
html,body,div,span,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,address,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,q,small,strong,sub,sup,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td{border:0;margin:0;padding:0}article,aside,figure,figure img,figcaption,hgroup,footer,header,nav,section,video,object{display:block}a img{border:0}figure{position:relative}figure img{width:amount}figure{margin:0;padding:0;}


body
{
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

header
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background: url("images/woman-wearing-white-long-sleeved-shirt-973401.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;


    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center 35%;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.opacity
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background: rgba(96, 59, 59, 0.7);
    overflow: hidden;
}


.navigation
{
    width: 700px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-right: 25%;
}

.navigation_list
{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 10px;
}

.navigation_list_item
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}



@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    header{
        width: 100%;
    }

    .opacity{
        width: 100%;
    }

    .logo{
        width: 474px;
        height: 369px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 50%;
        margin-left: 30%;
        margin-top: 50px;
    }

    .navigation
    {
        width: 700px;
        margin: auto;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 30px;
        margin-top: -20px;
        margin-right: 25%;
    }

    .navigation_list
    {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .navigation_list_item
    {
        display: inline-block;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<body>
<header>


        <div class="opacity">
            <div class="logo">
            </div>
        </div>
</header>
    <section>
<nav class="navigation">
<ul class="navigation_list">
    <li class="navigation_list_item">Over ons</li>
    <li class="navigation_list_item">Filosofie</li>
    <li class="navigation_list_item">Prijslijst</li>
    <li class="navigation_list_item">Specialisaties</li>
    <li class="navigation_list_item">Contact</li>
</ul>
</nav>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope someone can help me out with this problem. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest Way to Make Website Responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917664/fastest-way-to-make-website-responsive)

Comment: what he meant is to position the navigation at the middle of the screen i think!

Comment: Yes excactly @MidzElwekil. I tried it but the navigation stays at the same place the whole time.

Comment: @DenzelBaudet i have update your code below, now your navigation will be positioned at the middle of the screen, and also don't forget to add the viewport to the head of your page

Comment: Thank you very much @MidzElwekil. This is indeed the solution!

Comment: @MidzElwekil Ok don't care, the answer is still here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29400246/how-to-center-responsive-navigation-bar It took me 10 seconds to find it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to do something like this

```
.navigation
{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-right: 25%;
}

.navigation_list
{
    max-width: 700px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
```

make the navigation 100% and move the width to the ul (navigation list) and set the margin to 0 auto

one more thing to note, you need to add view port to the head of your page

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

to make you page responsive, you can read about [the view port here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)

hope this help

Comment: Why should he do that? What does that do? How does it answer the question? [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Your answer is just code. You should explain why he should use your code and how it solves his issue and not just blurt out code.

Comment: you are welcome, you will need to read more about responsive web pages as your page missing some codes.

here's some resources for you:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp
https://dzone.com/articles/using-csshtml-make-responsive
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-multi-screen-site
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Answer (score 1):

For a simple responsive design, try the following modification :
- Add this block

```
section {
    display: flex;
}
```

- Remove thoses lines

  `margin-right: 25%; /* two occurences */`